# How to pass id to get api url?(Angular)

Tags: angular

I have to pass an id property from GET api to another GET api
For example... I'm doing something like this..

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${value}
```

where '*${value}*' has to be replaced by 1,2,...
But this is showing me 404 not found error..
But if I try individually like this

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

I'm able to fetch results..
Please help me resolve this issue..

**.ts file**

```
viewPosts(value){
   console.log(value);
  this.apiService.getPosts(value).subscribe((result) => {
       console.log(result);
        ......

});  

 }
```

**ApiService file:**

```
getPosts(value:any):Observable<any>{

    const api='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${value}';
    return this.http.get(api);
  }
```

Comment: Replace `'` with `\``: `\`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${value}\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to change this code.

```
getPosts(value:any):Observable<any>{
  const api = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${value}`;
  return this.http.get(api);
}
```

you have to use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).